# C++ 32bit vs 64bit floating limit

Tags: c++, floating-point, mingw, limits

Given the code segment as follow, I just want to know

- why the maximum value of long double is smaller in 64bit than that in 32bit?
- why 64-bit version cannot expand as much digits as in 32-bit version to fill the "40" precision output?
- it seems that the values of LDBL_MIN and LDBL_MAX are equal, is that a bug?

I have looked into the float.h files in my machine but cannot find the explicit definition of these macro constants.

Testing Code (Platform = Win7-64bit)

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <iomanip>
cout<<"FLT_MAX   ="<< setprecision(40) << FLT_MAX  << endl;
cout<<"DBL_MAX   ="<< setprecision(40) << DBL_MAX  << endl;
cout<<"LDBL_MAX  ="<< setprecision(40) << LDBL_MAX << endl;
cout<<"FLT_MIN   ="<< setprecision(40) << FLT_MIN  << endl;
cout<<"DBL_MIN   ="<< setprecision(40) << DBL_MIN  << endl;
cout<<"LDBL_MIN  ="<< setprecision(40) << LDBL_MIN << endl;
```

32-bit outcome (MinGW-20120426)

```
FLT_MAX  =340282346638528859811704183484516925440
DBL_MAX  =1.797693134862315708145274237317043567981e+308
LDBL_MAX =1.189731495357231765021263853030970205169e+4932
FLT_MIN  =1.175494350822287507968736537222245677819e-038
DBL_MIN  =2.225073858507201383090232717332404064219e-308
LDBL_MIN =3.362103143112093506262677817321752602598e-4932
```

64-bit outcome (MinGW64-TDM 4.6)

```
FLT_MAX  =340282346638528860000000000000000000000
DBL_MAX  =1.7976931348623157e+308
LDBL_MAX =1.132619801677474e-317
FLT_MIN  =1.1754943508222875e-038
DBL_MIN  =2.2250738585072014e-308
LDBL_MIN =1.132619801677474e-317
```

Thanks.

[Edit]: Using the latest MinGW64-TGM 4.7.1, the "bugs" of LDBL_MAX, LDBL_MIN seems removed.

Comment: While `.cpp` is commonly used for C++ files, CPP is often used to refer to the C Pre-Processor. Fixed the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LDBL_MAX =1.132619801677474e-317` sounds like a bug somewhere. It's a requirement of the standard that every value representable as a `double` can also be represented as a `long double`, so it's not permissible for `LDBL_MAX < DBL_MAX`. Given that you haven't shown your real testing code, I personally would check that before blaming the compiler.

If there really is a (non-bug) difference in `long double` between the two, then the basis of that difference will be that your 32-bit compiler uses the older x87 floating point operations, which have 80 bit precision, and hence allow for an 80-bit `long double`.

Your 64-bit compiler uses the newer 64-bit floating point operations in x64. No 80-bit precision, and it doesn't bother switching to x87 instructions to implement a bigger `long double`.

There's probably more complication to it than that. For example not all x86 compilers necessarily have an 80-bit `long double`. How they make that decision depends on various things, possibly including the fact that SSE2 has 64-bit floating point ops. But the possibilities are that `long double` is the same size as `double`, or that it's bigger.

> why 64-bit version cannot expand as much digits as in 32-bit version
>   to fill the "40" precision output?

A double only has about 15 decimal digits of precision. Digits beyond that are sometimes informative, but usually misleading.

I can't remember what the standard says about `setprecision`, but assuming the implementation is allowed to draw a line where it stops generating digits, the precision of a `double` is a reasonable place to draw it. As for why one implementation decided to actually do it and the other didn't -- I don't know. Since they're different distributions, they might be using completely different standard libraries.

The same "spurious precision" is why you see `340282346638528859811704183484516925440` for FLT_MAX in one case, but `340282346638528860000000000000000000000` in the other. One compiler (or rather, one library implementation) has gone to the trouble to calculate lots of digits. The other has given up early and rounded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I make only a few assumptions:
1) that you tested this only on the 64 bit machine
2) that the compilers are different bit versions of the same sub-version (that is to say, they're practically sister compilers).

That having been said:

> From "ISO/IEC 14882 INTERNATIONAL STANDARD First edition 1998-09-01"
>
> 3.9.1 Fundamental types
>
> 1. There are three floating point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double. The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double. The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined. Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. Specializations of the standard template numeric_limits (18.2) shall specify the maximum and minimum values of each arithmetic type for an implementation.

Additionally different CPU's will have different effects on the end result as far as precision with higher level numbers. Same goes for compilers. VC++'s compiler won't behave same as borland, nor GCC/G++, and so on.

Comment: Sure i run the test program in a 64-bit box, and both gcc (32/64) are 4.6.x and i know these limits are somehow implementation-specific, but it seems that from the result, LDBL_MAX is a very small number, which is much much less that DBL_MAX (of order of 317+308=625) on 64-bit

Comment: My theory on why that is, is either because of how the compiler chose to represent it (either via a macro or a system request), or yes a bug.