# C# Math.pow( ) return Infinity?

Tags: c#, casting, return, double, floating-point-precision

i have problems with Math.pow in c# return infinity for example :

```
  double a=65;
  double b=331;
  Console.Write(Math.Pow(a,b));
  //but return infinty
```

but calculator for my pc not return 65 ^ 331 infinity there are real number return 
this :1.1866456424809823888425970808655e+600

i use cast to (long) but the result not same windows calculator
please i need the variable type is return same window calculator

Comment: So, what exactly is infinity on your scale?

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is, though I did my best to answer it. The closest to a question is your title, though your details indicate you already know the answer. So what's the question?

Answer (score 6):

`double` has a [limited range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); it cannot store this number.

Use `BigInteger`.

Comment: thanks but class bigintger return val not same result my calculat

Answer (score 5):

`Math.pow` has a limited range it can function with. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

I'm not sure why you're trying to calculate `65^331`. One work-around would be to use the [BigInteger class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

`BigInteger result = new BigInteger(Math.pow(65, 331))`

If that doesn't work, there's always good ol' fashioned multiplication:

```
BigInteger product = 1;
BigInteger a = 65;

for (int i = 0; i < 331; i++) {
    product = BigInteger.Multiply(product, a);
}
```

This should return the value you want.

Comment: thanks for help me but the problems not solve with class bigintger

Comment: i use 65 ^ 331 because i write sample programm to do encrypt text input ....(65 ^ 331 =1.1866456424809823888425970808655e+600) then do  1.1866456424809823888425970808655e+600 mod 17741 =530 [` 530 `] must final result to this processor is 530 .. [ 65 ^ 331 % 17741 ] ?

Answer (score 1):

If the value is out of range for the type, infinity is returned. So, yes, it can return infinity.

Comment: so what type unlimited storage " window calculator what type are use ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about IEEE754 floating point to understand the reasons for this.  Basically a number of that magniutude won't 'fit in a machine floating point format (commonly 32 or 64bit).

[C++ 32bit vs 64bit floating limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706368/c-32bit-vs-64bit-floating-limit) has information on the largest values these machine words will hold, but in short `BigInteger` is the correct way to handle such large numbers.

For example in Python (where integers can be of arbitrary magnitude):

```
>>>65**331
1186645642480982388842597080865547928975
8025124874226281286044593977851408626647
1648153565617569287290861365843808026786
6910699252797849188956233075264639216543
7504315383537154855617697699290248015932
2796464262757682229990775670822339468164
8291964549985945784276239845489091652362
0705054470856040542942680710474683036796
8985285030088564076789292802170819942388
3788422698744095551323695360171668455050
6467003204582429046323962276940067249678
5724338639806479202984280300919968748839
9063613316621160349502633982277117451890
1573217436770532915029575301234171172274
1482981646754524263087660074234008789062
5L
```